# Odd Field "dip" in gps_common::GPSFix message type

Tags: ros, gps-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been assessing whether this message type is appropriate for use with my Novatel GPS + IMU system, but raised an eyebrow when "dip" followed "pitch" and "roll". Where's yaw? Is this just a typo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46252/odd-field-%22dip%22-in-gps_common::gpsfix-message-type/) by [Bryce Hathaway](https://answers.ros.org/users/3344/bryce-hathaway/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe dip refers to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dip_angle

For yaw, I think you're looking for "track"

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0